# Android Page Curl implementation

Tags: android, page-curl

I'm using this implementation in my application [Android Page Curl Animation](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/) , but I want to set the images to be shown on fullscreen without any extra borders or elements near them. I want to set the images and the surface view to fit the screen dimensions, but didn't find how to do that. Any ideas where to look/change so I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just set the margins as 0f.
I used SHOW_ONE_PAGE, hence here is the supporting code which worked for me.

```
private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
    //@Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
        mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
        mCurlView.setMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```